# Quadratic variation of $w^2(t)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value, quadratic-variation

What is the quadratic variation of ($w(t))^2$, where $w(t)$ denotes a Wiener- process and what is the expected value of it? What is $E([(w(t))^2])$?

My result is: $2(t^2)$, but knowing myself, I am not 100% sure about it.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028350/quadratic-variations-of-brownian-motion-squared for discussions about the quadratic variation of $W(t)^2$. To find $\E\left[W(t)^2\right]$, just recall that $W(t)\sim N(0,t)$ and so $\E\left[W(t)^2\right] = t$ (remember, the second moment of a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variable is $\sigma^2$).

Comment: Yes, it was right in my solution as well...but my question is about the expected value of the quadratic variation of Wiener- process squared...Is my result right in this case?